# kafka Kraft + confluent platform versions vs apache Kafka versions

Tags: apache-kafka, kraft

we can download the latest kafka kraft version - 3.5.1 from apache link - https://kafka.apache.org/downloads

but we are wondering if the same equivalent version like 3.X can also download from other providers as confluent

we search in confluent site but we not sure if we can download **free** the relevant rpms or the relevant tar files in order to install the brokers machine

our target is to install Kafka Kraft lab cluster but we want to understand what the other providers that supply **free** download packages in order to installed brokers/controllers machines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First - https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/versions-interoperability.html

Confluent Platform *includes* Apache Kafka (and releases around 6 months of any Kafka release). There is no "Confluent Kafka"... Therefore, there is no true difference in what you choose in order to have KRaft available.

> free rpms

They are, unless you choose to use Enterprise licensed packages like `cp-server` or `control-center`. https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/installing_cp/rhel-centos.html

> other providers

Apache BigTop is the only other one I can think of. Otherwise, plenty of people have containerized Kafka, such as Bitnami and RedHat so it can run in Kubernetes, for example.